# Text label color not matching fivethirtyeight theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I'm working on a shiny app that creates reactive charts.
For one of them - a donut chart - I'm not able to make the legend colors match the text label colors.
A reactive dataframe is created when brushing on another chart. This df is then used to create the donut chart.
For example the dataframe from the brush action looks like this

```
dng<-structure(list(Outcome = structure(3:1, levels = c("Home", "Draw", 
"Away"), class = "factor"), Counts = 4:2, `%` = c(44.44, 33.33, 
22.22), fraction = c(0.44, 0.33, 0.22), ymax = c(0.44, 0.77, 
0.99), ymin = c(0, 0.44, 0.77), labelPosition = c(0.22, 0.605, 
0.88), label = c("Away:\n 44.44%", "Draw:\n 33.33%", "Home:\n 22.22%"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the code I've written for my donut chart

```
output$plotui3 <- renderPlot({
  dng<-cutoffs()
  dng$fraction<- round(dng$Counts/sum(dng$Counts),2)
  dng$ymax<- cumsum(dng$fraction)
  dng$ymin<- c(0,head(dng$ymax, n=-1))
  dng$labelPosition <- (dng$ymax + dng$ymin) / 2
  dng$label <- ifelse(dng$Counts==0, "", paste0(dng$Outcome, ":\n ", dng$'%',"%"))

  
  g3<-ggplot(dng, aes(ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,xmax=4,xmin=3,fill=Outcome)) +
    geom_rect()+
    geom_text( x=2, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label,color=Outcome), size=6,show.legend = F)+
    coord_polar(theta="y") +
    xlim(c(0, 4)) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme_void()+
    scale_fill_fivethirtyeight(labels = c("Win", "Draw","Lose"),breaks = c("Home","Draw","Away"))+
    theme(legend.position="bottom",legend.text=element_text(size=20),legend.title = element_text(size=20))
  g3
})
```

However the color of the labels are always off

[image]

I would like to have the labels matching the color of the legend so that

```
clrs = c(Home = "#008FD5", Draw = "#FF2700", Away = "#77AB43")
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `scale_fill_fivethirtyeight` which applies to the fill, but the text color is not set. Add `scale_color_fivethirtyeight` as well.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes) # scale_*_fivethirtyeight
# library(hrbrthemes) # theme_ipsum

ggplot(dng, aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=Outcome)) +
    geom_rect() +
    geom_text(x=2, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label, color=Outcome), size=6, show.legend=FALSE) +
    coord_polar(theta="y") +
    xlim(c(0, 4)) +
    # theme_ipsum() +
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_fivethirtyeight(labels=c("Win", "Draw", "Lose"), breaks=c("Home", "Draw", "Away")) +
    scale_color_fivethirtyeight(labels=c("Win", "Draw", "Lose"), breaks=c("Home", "Draw", "Away")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=20), legend.title=element_text(size=20))
```

[image: pie chart with both fill and color set to the same values]

Side note: multiple `theme*` functions *update* values from all previous themes set. When you use a "whole theme" function such as `theme_ipsum` and `theme_void`, they tend to update *all attributes*. In this case, the call to `theme_ipsum()` is completely overridden (and thus has no impact) by `theme_void()`:

```r
setdiff(names(theme_void()), names(theme_ipsum()))
# character(0)
```

If there were any attributes in ipsum not set in void, then `theme_ipsum()` would have something preserved.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and the side note is really helpful as well!